# DataTables - Set how many pagination links display

Tags: jquery, pagination, datatables

using DataTables, how can I set the number of pagination links that display?  As seen in below screen shot, I would like to limit the buttons to only a few so prevent it from being so long.

[image]

I am sure this is possible, I'm just not sure what to even look for as the option for setting it.  I would prefer to only show FIRST,PREVIOUS,1,2..29,NEXT,LAST

```
$.fn.DataTable.ext.pager.numbers_length = 7;
```

and it does not work.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Is this what you are looking for:

[image]

http://live.datatables.net/biyoqesi/98/edit

```
$(document).ready( function () {
  $.fn.DataTable.ext.pager.numbers_length = 4;
  var table = $('#example').DataTable({"pagingType": "full_numbers"});
} );
```

Comment: @all relative to the value I was trying to set in the numbers_length.  WOW.  Strange how that makes a difference.  This works great! Thank you!